# Difference between Redis Replication and Redis Sentinel

Tags: redis, replication, redis-sentinel

I am trying to understand if the Redis replication (described [here](http://redis.io/topics/replication)) relates to the Redis Sentinel (described [here](http://redis.io/topics/sentinel)) or are totally different approaches to data replication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use them both together. If you have a master and a couple of slaves, replication makes sure that data between all three remains consistent, but sentinel will handle promoting a slave to a master if the master dies, redirecting new requests to the new master, and notifying someone about what has happened.